# If Swing models' getters aren't thread-safe, how do you handle them?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

It is well known that updating a Swing GUI must be done exclusively in the EDT. Less is advertised that *reading* stuff from the GUI must/should also be done in the EDT. For instance, let's take [ButtonModel's isSelected()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html#isSelected()) method, which tells (for instance) ToggleButton's state ("down" or "up").

In every example I've seen, `isSelected()` is liberally queried from the main or whichever thread. But when I look at DefaultButtonModel's implementation, it's not synchronized, and the value is not volatile. So, strictly speaking, `isSelected()` could return garbage if it's read from any other thread than the one from which it's set (which is the EDT, when the user pushes the button). Or am I mistaken?

I originally thought about this when shocked by item #66 in Bloch's Effective Java, this example:

```
public class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while(!stopRequested) i++;
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

Contrary to what is seems, that program never terminates, on some machines at least. Updating the `stopRequested` flag from the main thread is invisible to the background thread. The situation can be fixed with synchronized getters & setters, or by setting the flag `volatile`.

So:

1. Is querying a Swing model's state outside the EDT (strictly speaking) wrong?
2. If not, how come?
3. If yes, how do you handle it? By luck, or by some clever workaround? InvokeAndWait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, not wrong, but as with any cross-thread communication you need to ensure you provide appropriate thread-safety mechanisms if you decide to do this (e.g. use of `synchronized` or `volatile`).  For example I typically write my own `TableModel` implementations, typically sitting on `List<X>` where `X` is my business object.  If I intend for other threads to query the List I will make this a synchronized `Collection`.  It's also worth noting I would never normally update the `List` from other threads; only query it.
2. Because it's exactly the same situation as with any other multi-threaded application.
3. I typically make the collection synchronized (see 1).

**Caveat**

Despite my answer above I typically **do not** access models directly outside of the EDT.  As Carl mentions, if the action of performing an update is invoked via some GUI action there's no need to perform any synchronization as the code is already being run by the EDT.  However, if I wish to perform some background processing that will lead to the model being changed I will typically invoke a `SwingWorker` and then assign the results of `doInBackground()` from within the `done()` method (i.e. on the EDT).  This is cleaner IMHO as the `doInBackground()` method has no side-effects.

Comment: I would have to disagree with #1, because it is misleading to newbies. They should learn the rule "accessing swing outside the EDT is a no-no" and only after they fully understand why should they then break the rules. A newbie is only going to see your first three words "No, not wrong...". Not to mention, threading is difficult enough as it is without having to worry whether you are properly synchronizing your model. The only reason I didn't vote you down is because your Caveat section is the correct way to handle it.

Comment: My apologies for calling Joonas a "newbie". :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is wrong; unless both threads synchronize ***on the same object or use some other memory barrier, like volatile, as defined by the JMM*** one or the other can observe inconsistent memory contents.  Period.  End of story.  Violating this might work on some, even many, architectures, but it will eventually bite you on the hiney.

The problem here is that with a few exceptions where you provide the model, such as what Adamski referred to, the Swing code is not going to synchronize on anything.

And it's worth noting that the JMM (Java Memory Model) has changed with JSR-133 in Java 5 in very important ways, so behavior with a J4 and earlier JVM may well yield different results than J5 and later.  The revised JMM is, as you would expect, considerably improved.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The JMM http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/ is difficult to understand. Trying to find clever ways around it is a sure-fire way to create buggy applications. Stick with the rules until you feel you are at expert level.

Comment: Thinking about the architecture is probably not the best way to look at it. Runtime compilers make use of the JMM (for instance using registers). It's really not worth trying to guess what weird things the compiler is going to do. / The pre-1.5 JMM doesn't make sense and was never correctly implemented. Sun's implementation of 1.4 uses the 1.5 JMM.

Comment: @Tom: My point was that testing will not reveal any problems, quite possibly because on many architectures there might not be any.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is in general not only not thread-safe, but thread-hostile. However, most models, other than Swing text, are thread-agnostic. This means that you can use models in any thread, provided you use standard thread protection. Swing text was an attempt to be thread-safe but failed, and is in fact thread-hostile. Only use `Document`s from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

The usual advice is to run potentially long running (typically blocking) tasks off the EDT. However, threading is difficult. `SwingWorker` is a popular way to induce bad design - avoid it. Try to keep EDT and non-EDT code separated. Try not to share mutable state.

Threading bugs are difficult. You might not see them on your machine, but customers may well do. Perhaps bugs appear due to optimisations in later versions of the JRE. Thread bugs are difficult to track. Therefore, be conservative. Even blocking the EDT briefly is better than nasty bugs.

Comment: "SwingWorker is a popular way to induce bad design - avoid it." - Not sure I agree with you there.  How else would you suggest performing background processing?

Comment: I agree with Adamski that if you disagree with using SwingWorker that it would be nice to have the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

1. I never worried much about it, but strictly speaking, yes, it's probably wrong.
2. N/A.
3. I let changes in the GUI update (via listeners) models of my own construction, that are not contained or constructed by Swing. There's never any need to ask the GUI because the GUI updates the model.

Since I create the models myself (this can be something very simple, such as a String with getter/setter and PropertyChangeSupport), I can make the accessors synchronized if I want. I rarely encounter flaky behavior due to thread contention or such.

Comment: Re: #1, you should worry about it, because accessing swing outside the EDT is bad bad bad. Of course YOU never see the problem, but I guarantee your customers will, and they won't be able to explain what is going on because it is so intermittent, so your program will forever be flaky.

Comment: As I go on to explain, I have no reason to worry because I've been "instinctively" doing the right thing all along: I code in such a way that I never have any need to access GUI component properties from outside the EDT. My model objects get updated from the EDT and I can make them thread safe. That's why I have few customer complaints - not about this topic, anyway. Also, I try not to worry about anything because otherwise my stomach gives me trouble. So I won't worry about your admonition and downvote ;)

Comment: @Carl, while appreciate the fact that you "instinctively" have been doing the right thing, you unfortunately gave bad advice to Joonas there. No hard feelings.

Comment: @Nemi, which part of "yes, it's probably wrong" did you feel is subject to being misconstrued?

Comment: You probably don't loose sleep over it, but it is bad advice and should not be taken by anyone else!

Answer (score 1):

> If yes, how do you handle it? By luck, or by some clever workaround? InvokeAndWait?

Others have already mentioned [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and you're already aware of the [`invoke*`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) methods. [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) can also be useful. There are no silver bullets for safe multi-threaded programming, though a good design will go a long way.

There are things you can do to detect bugs. If you design a method to only be invoked from the *event dispatch thread*, guard it so that it will fail if someone tries to access if from another thread:

```
  public static class ThreadUnsafeAccessException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  }

  @Override public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
      throw new ThreadUnsafeAccessException();
    }
    return decorated.getElementAt(index);
  }
```

Retrofitting this approach to an existing application that does a lot of setup on the main application thread might mean some major refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question and Software Monkey has the right answer. If you want to do effective threading you must fully understand the [Java](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) [Memory](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/) [Model](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html) (JMM). Note that the java memory model *has changed* with JSR-133, so a lot of old threading examples you find will simply be wrong. E.g., the volatile keyword has changed from being almost useless to now being nearly as enforced as the synchronized keyword.

Additionally, we now have true, ubiquitous multi-core cpu's, which means true multi-threading. Multi-threading up until a few years ago was only faking it on single-core cpu's, which is why so much bad sample code is out there. It used to work. Now it won't.

Seriously, if Joshua Bloch can get it wrong, tread very carefully. It is complicated stuff (and yes, his code is wrong. Make that variable volatile and it will work in all cases though).

Oh yeah, Adamski has it right. Use a `SwingWorker` to make sure long-running code is done in a background thread and that when it is done manipulating the data, it should access Swing on the `done()` method. If you need to read, do it *before* making your `SwingWorker` and make the info `final`.

Example of code that would be called on the EDT, most likely in an ActionListener or somesuch (psuedocode):

```
public void someOverlySimpleExampleThatIsCalledOnEDT() {
   /*
    * Any code run here is guaranteed to happen-before 
    * the start of a background thread.
    */
   final String text = myTextField().getText();
   SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {
      private volatile List data;
      public Object doInBackground() {
         //happens in background thread. No Swing access
         data = myDao.getDataFromInternet(text);
         return null;
      }
      public void done() {
         //Happens in EDT. Swing away Merrill
         loadDataIntoJTable(data);
      }
   }
   sw.execute();
   /* 
    * Any code run here happens concurrently with doInBackground(). Be careful. 
    * Usually leave empty
    */
}
```

Comment: Curiously, your example (as far as I understand it) does exactly the mistake that I was concerned about: you call `getText()` in an arbitrary thread, and thus you may get incorrect content in the `text` variable.

Comment: A couple of more comments still: 1. Bloch's code is intentionally wrong, it's a (IMHO stunning) demonstration. 2. I agree with you in that the increasing number of cores will cause more and more concurrency bugs to pop up in the near future. We can't fake it any more :-)

Comment: @Joonas, you are correct, my code was not clear. This is code that would be called on the EDT, most likely in an ActionListener. That way you know that all access outside the SwingWorker is on the EDT. Usually a button press or some other such action has just taken place. I edited the method name to make it more clear.